# New Official Google App Engine Maven Archetype Missing?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just read the App Engine 1.7.4 release announcement:

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/12/app-engine-174-released.html

In the linked release notes it points to a guide about the new feature of using Maven:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven

That guide talks about using a maven archetype like:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and filtering for

```
com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype
```

I can't find the archetype for some reason and when I click on the link the guide has to search for the archetype in Maven Central, I get no results:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.google.appengine.archetype

Am I missing something? Can anyone let me know how to use that archetype?

Comment: g:"com.google.appengine.archetypes"

Comment: you should first create a local/remote repository catalog under Window-> Properties -> Maven -> Archetypes with [http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml] as catalog file incase of remote catalog

Comment: Download [http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml] file and give path of this downloaded file as catalog file in case of local  repository catalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like sync delay. The archetype is already there:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cguestbook-archetype

Try clearing your local repo and do archetype:generate again:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.appengine.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=guestbook-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.4
```

Comment: Yes, I see it other now, too. I also see the 1.7.4 version of the plugin now, too. The maven central search didn't seem to work because the group was com.Google.appengine.archetypes rather than com.Google.appengine.archetype that was linked to in the guide. Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add maven central catalog file

1. download this file
   http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=archetype-catalog.xml
2. preference -> maven -> add catalog info